# Get JSON object in Clojure

Tags: json, clojure, clostache

I have such code:

```
(defn my-journey-page [locale]
  (render-string
    (read-template "myJourney") {:api      (:api props)
                                 :feedback (:feedback props)}))
...
(def props (get-props))
...
(def default-props {:api      "https://dev"
                    :feedback (json/write-str {:feedback  {:en "en" :fi "fi" :sv "sv"}
                                               :survey {:en "en" :fi "fi" :sv "sv"}})})
```

And I need to help with putting a valid JSON object to **feedback** key. I use clostache as a template. In current case it returns:

```
var obj = { 
  feedback: '{&quot;feedback&quot;:{&quot;en&quot;:&quot;en&quot;,&quot;fi&quot;:&quot;fi&quot;,&quot;sv&quot;:&quot;sv&quot;},&quot;survey&quot;:{&quot;en&quot;:&quot;en&quot;,&quot;fi&quot;:&quot;fi&quot;,&quot;sv&quot;:&quot;sv&quot;}}'
}
```

How can I get it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any mustache-based template system, the following should apply:

You didn't show what your template looks like, but you should be able to get the value of your `feedback` variable without HTML-escaping by writing `{{{feedback}}}` (triple braces) instead of `{{feedback}}` in the template.

Comment: Actually, I use clostache. I'll update question with it

Comment: OK, my answer should work with all mustache-based template systems.